# Shiny render plot immediately instead of waiting for the entire web app

Tags: r, shiny, render

I have multiple renderPlot({}) in my shiny app. I want the plots to start appearing as soon as they are ready to be rendered instead of waiting for all the renderPlots to finish execution. Is there a way to be able to do this?

```
renderPlotly({
   datatablevariable <- ReactiveFn1()
   plot_ly()
})

renderPlotly({
   datatablevariable <- ReactiveFn2()
   plot_ly()
})
```

In the code above, I want shiny to show the first plot as soon as ReactiveFn1() is done instead of waiting for ReactiveFn2() to be done as well. Hope this example helps!

Comment: minimal example would help

Comment: Example added above

Comment: is that inside the server or ui part of the app?